# How to use <f:loadBundle> tag inside <ui:composition> tag

Tags: jsf-2

I want to use `<f:loadBundle>` tag in my view. I know that I can declare it inside `faces-config.xml`, but for a reason I want to use it in my view. I am using the tag in this manner but it is not working. I am using it inside `<ui:composition>` tag.

```
<h:head>
    <title>Email Content</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <ui:composition template="./WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="content">
            <f:loadBundle basename="presentationBeans.homepage.messages" var="msgs"/>
            <h:form id="emailContent_Review" >
                <p:growl id="growl" showDetail="true" />
                <p:panel id="panel"  
                    header="#{msgs.ECR_panelHeader}" 
                    style="border-color: #000000;width: 960px;position: absolute;left: 150px;height: 370px" >
                    <p:dataTable value="#{emailContent_Review.emailContent}"
                        var="emailContent"
                        selection="#{emailContent_Review.selectedEmailContent}"
                        emptyMessage="#{msgs.ECR_tableEmptyMessage}" 
                        widgetVar="portalsTable"
                        rows="8" height="350" paginator="true">
                        <f:facet name="header" >
                        </f:facet>
                    </p:dataTable>
                </p:panel>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</h:body>
```

What I am doing wrong? Also I read that

> To make use of a template, you use a 'ui:composition' tag with a 'template' attribute. 
>       Facelets removes all tags outside the  tag - that is, the doctype declaration, html, head, title and body tags. This is necessary because the `<ui:composition>` is replaced with the template that contains its own set of html, head, title, and body tags.

If I want to use my properties file in the head section, then how can I use it? Because head section is outside the `<ui:composition>` tag. I mean to say, if I want to do this

```
<h:head>
    <title>#{msgs.indexWindowTitle}</title>
</h:head>
```

then how can I use my properties file outside `<ui:composition>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is indeed not going to work. Change your master template `layout.xhtml` to replace the title by a template insert placeholder:

```
<h:head>
    <title><ui:insert name="title">Default title</ui:insert></title>
</h:head>
```

Then change your template client to define it:

```
<ui:composition template="./WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">
        <f:loadBundle basename="presentationBeans.homepage.messages" var="msgs"/>
        #{msgs.indexWindowTitle}
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="content">
        ...
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Note that you don't need to repeat the `<f:loadBundle>` for `<ui:define name="content">`.

Comment: Hi thnaks, Sorry for late reply. Thank you very much :) ;)

Comment: @BalusC normally you want a `f:loadBundle` is your master template but now you recommend to put it into each view?

Answer (score 0):

I have struck upon an approach that works well for me on Mojarra 2.1.x, perhaps give it a tumble.  Tweaking @BalusC's example:

```
<ui:composition>
    <f:loadBundle basename="presentationBeans.homepage.messages" var="msgs"/>

    <ui:decorate template="./WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml">
        <ui:define name="title">
            #{msgs.indexWindowTitle}
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="content">
            ...
        </ui:define>
    </ui:decorate>
</ui:composition>
```

My approach of nesting the templated ui:decorate within my bare ui:composition tags works well for me because I often want to declare one f:loadBundle tag that is shared by all of my nested ui:define's.  Not sure what kinds of extra machinations I'm making the kernel do when I do this however, or if I'm exploiting an incomplete implementation of the spec to get what I want.  YMMV